# World Position changes after animation - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and I am trying to implement swipe gestures in my Card stack, have managed to create a stack using scripting by using prefabs, the stack is dynamic and can have up to 220 cards.

[image]

**The problem** is with the gestures when I swipe left the card from the front of the stack should get removed from the stack and another card should be added to the back of the stack, In total there should only be a total of **4 cards visible**.

**Snippet #1** where i am creating my gameobjects and setting them active/inactive

```
public void SetCardNumber ()
{
    Positions = new Vector3[4];
    CardScales = new Vector3[4];
    Positions [0] = new Vector3 (Screen.width / 2, (Screen.height / 2) + 135f, 0f);
    Positions [1] = new Vector3 (Screen.width / 2, (Screen.height / 2) + 90f, 0f);
    Positions [2] = new Vector3 (Screen.width / 2, (Screen.height / 2) + 45f, 0f);
    Positions [3] = new Vector3 (Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 0f);

    CardScales [0] = new Vector3 (0.85f, 0.85f, 0f);
    CardScales [1] = new Vector3 (0.9f, 0.9f, 0f);
    CardScales [2] = new Vector3 (0.95f, 0.95f, 0f);
    CardScales [3] = new Vector3 (1f, 1f, 0f);

    InActivePositions = new Vector3 (0f, 0f, 0f);
    InActiveCardScales = new Vector3 (1f, 1f, 0f);

    Cards = new GameObject[words.Length];
    CardNumber = new GameObject[words.Length];
    CardText = new GameObject[words.Length];
    ShowSentenceBulb = new GameObject[words.Length];
    for (int i = 0, j = words.Length; i <= words.Length - 1; i++,j--) {
        GameObject obj = (GameObject)Instantiate (CardPrefab) as GameObject;
        Cards [i] = obj;
        CurrentCardCounter++;

        Cards [i].transform.SetParent (panel.transform, false);
        foreach (Transform child in obj.transform) {
            if (child.tag == "TextCardNumber")
                CardNumber [i] = child.gameObject;
            if (child.tag == "TextCard")
                CardText [i] = child.gameObject;
            if (child.tag == "ShowSentenceBulb")
                ShowSentenceBulb [i] = child.gameObject;
        }

        if (i == 0) {
            CardText [i].GetComponent<Text> ().text = CurrentWordList [j - 1];
            CardText [i].GetComponent<Text> ().fontSize = 70;
            CardText [i].GetComponent<Text> ().color = new Color (255, 215, 0);
        } else
            CardText [i].GetComponent<Text> ().text = CurrentWordList [j - 1];
        CardNumber [i].GetComponent<Text> ().text = j + "";
        ShowSentenceBulb [i].GetComponent<Button> ().onClick.AddListener (ShowSentenceOnBulbClick);
    }

    var quotient = CurrentCardCounter / 4;

    for (int k = 3; CurrentCardCounter > 0; CurrentCardCounter--,k--) {
        if (CurrentCardCounter <= (4 * (quotient - 1))) {
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 1].SetActive (false);
        }
        else {
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter-1].transform.position = Positions [k];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter-1].transform.localScale = CardScales [k];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter-1].SetActive (true);
        }

    }
    CurrentCardCounter=words.Length-1;
    swipeAnim= Cards[CurrentCardCounter].GetComponent<Animator>();
}
```

The way i am handling this is by creating all the gameObjects at the start of the scene but making only 4 Active, and whenever i swipe left a new card is set to Active.

**Snippet #2** Left swipe-gesture to remove front card from stack

```
if (swipeLeft && CurrentCardCounter > 0 && !isCardShowingSentence) {

        swipeAnim.enabled = true;
        swipeAnim.Play ("swipe");
        if (CurrentCardCounter > 0) {
            CurrentCardCounter--;
            swipeAnim = Cards [CurrentCardCounter].GetComponent<Animator> ();

            if (CurrentCardCounter > 3) {
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter].transform.position = Positions [3];
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter].transform.localScale = CardScales [3];
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 1].transform.position = Positions [2];
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 1].transform.localScale = CardScales [2];
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 2].transform.position = Positions [1];
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 2].transform.localScale = CardScales [1];
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 3].SetActive (true);
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 3].transform.position = Positions [0];
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 3].transform.localScale = CardScales [0];
            } else if (CurrentCardCounter > 2) {
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter].transform.position = Positions [3];
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter].transform.localScale = CardScales [3];
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 1].transform.position = Positions [2];
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 1].transform.localScale = CardScales [2];
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 2].transform.position = Positions [1];
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 2].transform.localScale = CardScales [1];
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 3].SetActive (true);
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 3].transform.position = Positions [0];
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 3].transform.localScale = CardScales [0];
            } else if (CurrentCardCounter > 1) {
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter].transform.position = Positions [3];
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter].transform.localScale = CardScales [3];
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 1].transform.localScale = CardScales [2];
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 1].transform.position = Positions [2];
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 2].transform.localScale = CardScales [1];
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 2].transform.position = Positions [1];
            } else if (CurrentCardCounter > 0) {
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter].transform.localScale = CardScales [3];
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter].transform.position = Positions [3];
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 1].transform.localScale = CardScales [2];
                Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 1].transform.position = Positions [2];
            }
        } else {
            //swipeAnim = Cards [0].GetComponent<Animator> ();
            //swipeAnim.enabled = true;
            //swipeAnim.Play ("shake");
            //swipeAnim.enabled = false;
        }

    }
```

this is all handled gracefully but there is also a right swipe gesture(to get back the swiped card, the swiped card is added to the front of stack and the card which was added to the back would again be made Inactive) which messes up the position of the gameobjects, i dont know why.

**Snippet #3** Right swipe-gesture to get back the swiped card back and remove the back card from the stack

```
if (swipeRight && CurrentCardCounter < words.Length - 1  && !isCardShowingSentence) {

        if (CurrentCardCounter < words.Length) {
            swipeAnim = Cards [CurrentCardCounter+1].GetComponent<Animator> ();
            swipeAnim.enabled = true;
            swipeAnim.Play ("swipeBack");
            CurrentCardCounter++;
        }

        if (CurrentCardCounter > 6) {
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 1].transform.position = Positions[3];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 1].transform.localScale = CardScales[3];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 2].transform.position = Positions[2];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 2].transform.localScale = CardScales[2];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 3].transform.position = Positions[1];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 3].transform.localScale = CardScales[1];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 4].SetActive (false);
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 4].transform.position = InActivePositions;
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 4].transform.localScale = InActiveCardScales;
        }else if (CurrentCardCounter > 5) {
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 1].transform.position = Positions[3];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 1].transform.localScale = CardScales[3];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 2].transform.position = Positions[2];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 2].transform.localScale = CardScales[2];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 3].transform.position = Positions[1];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 3].transform.localScale = CardScales[1];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 4].SetActive (false);
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 4].transform.position = InActivePositions;
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 4].transform.localScale = InActiveCardScales;
        }else if (CurrentCardCounter > 4) {
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 1].transform.position = Positions[3];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 1].transform.localScale = CardScales[3];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 2].transform.position = Positions[2];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 2].transform.localScale = CardScales[2];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 3].transform.position = Positions[1];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 3].transform.localScale = CardScales[1];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 4].SetActive (false);
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 4].transform.position = InActivePositions;
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 4].transform.localScale = InActiveCardScales;
        } else if (CurrentCardCounter > 3) {
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 1].transform.position = Positions[3];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 1].transform.localScale = CardScales[3];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 2].transform.position = Positions[2];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 2].transform.localScale = CardScales[2];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 3].transform.position = Positions[1];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 3].transform.localScale = CardScales[1];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 4].SetActive (false);
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 4].transform.position = InActivePositions;
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 4].transform.localScale = InActiveCardScales;
        } else if (CurrentCardCounter > 2) {
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 1].transform.position = Positions[3];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 1].transform.localScale = CardScales[3];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 2].transform.position = Positions[2];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 2].transform.localScale = CardScales[2];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 3].transform.position = Positions[1];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 3].transform.localScale = CardScales[1];
        } else if (CurrentCardCounter > 1) {
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 1].transform.position = Positions[3];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 1].transform.localScale = CardScales[3];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 2].transform.position = Positions[2];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 2].transform.localScale = CardScales[2];
        } else if (CurrentCardCounter > 0) {
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 1].transform.position = Positions[3];
            Cards [CurrentCardCounter - 1].transform.localScale = CardScales[3];
        }
    }
```

This problem has been giving me headaches for, i dont know how long, Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I believe you see only two cards when put one from the top of the stack to the bottom.In real life.

Comment: 4 cards get visible, and when there are only lets say, 3 cards left, they seem like they are coming to the front since i am changing the position and scale